# How to replace a word in a Python string

Tags: python, string

I want to replace for example the word "p1" with "p10" in the below string sentence. I tried several methods but failed. Hope you can provide me with a simple python code of how to solve this problem. Cheers.

```
"(2*(-2 + d)*m1^2*j[MI, 0, 1] + 2*(-3 + d)*m1^2*j[MI, 1, 1]*(m1^2 - m2 - SPD[p1, p1]) - (-2 + d) * j[MI, 1, 0]*(m1^2 + m2 - SPD[p1, p1]))\/(2*m1^2*((m1^2 - m2)^2 - 2*(m1^2 + m2)*SPD[p1, p1] + SPD[p1, p1]^2))"
```

Comment: What methods did you try that failed? In what ways did they fail?

Comment: I solved it. Just by using the in-built function replace("p1","p10").

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.replace`:

```
s = "(2*(-2 + d)*m1^2*j[MI, 0, 1] + 2*(-3 + d)*m1^2*j[MI, 1, 1]*(m1^2 - m2 - SPD[p1, p1]) - (-2 + d) * j[MI, 1, 0]*(m1^2 + m2 - SPD[p1, p1]))\/(2*m1^2*((m1^2 - m2)^2 - 2*(m1^2 + m2)*SPD[p1, p1] + SPD[p1, p1]^2))"
s.replace('p1', 'p10')
```

or you can use a regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub('p1', 'p10', s)
```

output:

```
'(2*(-2 + d)*m1^2*j[MI, 0, 1] + 2*(-3 + d)*m1^2*j[MI, 1, 1]*(m1^2 - m2 - SPD[p10, p10]) - (-2 + d) * j[MI, 1, 0]*(m1^2 + m2 - SPD[p10, p10]))\\/(2*m1^2*((m1^2 - m2)^2 - 2*(m1^2 + m2)*SPD[p10, p10] + SPD[p10, p10]^2))'
```